# Consider NA as factor level for several variables

Tags: r, missing-data, categorical-data

I am trying to run a k-modes on a big categorical dataset.

There are several NA in each variable but I want to keep this information because for me it is meaningful.

K-modes does not work on a dataset with NAs, hence, I am looking for a fast approach to consider as factor level all the NA in all the variables.

I have read many questions but the answers are exclusively applicable in a name-by-name fashion.

Any suggestion using R?

```
mydf <- data.frame(a = factor(c("a", NA, NA)), b = factor(c("b", NA, NA)), c = factor(c("yo", NA, NA)))
```

Comment: Can you just assign all NA values to some arbitrary number which is un-correlated with all other data? i.e. `mydf[ is.na(mydf) ] <- -999`

Comment: because this approach does not work

Comment: In what sense does it not work?

Comment: try it yourself please

Comment: So, the approach does work pending you make the necessary transformations in order to manipulate the data. I was not providing an answer, merely a suggestion.

Comment: Yes thank you Sam! I didn't know about that transformation

Comment: Glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(a = factor(c("a", NA, NA)), b = factor(c("b", NA, NA)), c = factor(c("yo", NA, NA)))
```

From factor to character

```
mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Substitution

```
mydf[is.na(mydf)]<-"Something"
```

Back to factor

```
mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, as.character), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Your new factor

```
factor(mydf$a)
[1] a         Something Something
Levels: a Something
```

Comment: So exactly what I said

Comment: Yes, but with step by step explanation

Comment: OP also said this approach does not work so we should hold off jumping to any conclusions before receiving more info.

Comment: Sam approach did not include `mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` hence it was not working. Concerning @Terru_theTerror approach, it works. Any idea how can I apply the "back to factor" step only to character variables and not numeric?